# Is it possible to pay ICO consultants in the ICO's new currency?

Tags: erc-20, ico

I am working as a consultant on a new ETH based ICO campaign.

The arrangement is that they will pay me with their new tokens they are issuing through their ICO. The problem is, as far as I know, tokens are automatically paid through a smart contract to investors based on their ETH contribution.

I am wondering if there is anyway I can guarantee receiving the tokens? I have had to turn to stack overflow to get an answer, it is incredibly difficult to find relevant, reliable information online.

Are they able to transfer their tokens prior to their ICO to an ether wallet?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they able to transfer their tokens prior to their ICO to an ether wallet?

Yes, this is certainly possible.

> I am wondering if there is anyway I can guarantee receiving the tokens?

No, I don't see how. It will be up to those who control the tokens (initially whoever that created them) to send them to you. If they choose not to do that, then you won't get them. If you want assurance that you'll be compensated (via tokens or any other means) if you do the work, then you'll want to sign a contract.

Comment: Hi Smarx, thank you so much for the help

With the kind of work I am doing, I could get them to send the tokens prior to me submitting a final version of the work. It is animation. I figured I would provide a low definition draft, get the tokens, then send them the HD version.

Comment: So you're saying they are 100% capable of sending tokens prior to the ICO, therefore meaning they could send me the tokens when I finish the work. As it would be about 1 month prior to the ICO commencing. This is assuming of course they have created the currency at this time.

Comment: Yes. It's of course also possible for them to create the currency in such a way that it _can't_ be transferred to you, but they'd have to go out of their way to do that.